# Getting an error when connecting to phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, xampp

I'm getting the following error when I'm connecting to phpmyadmin. I have already start mysql and apache.[image]

Can anyone please give me the solution for this.

Comment: I understand that something is wrong: the host, the username or the password.

Comment: How should I change those?